# How to setup the connection time out with "file://" protocol

Tags: java

Let said I have a file call `ext.properties` that was located in `SERVER_A/Config` folder

If the code can access the SERVER_A, then following code is working fine, and handle the work for the InputStream

```
try{
    String remote = "SERVER_A/Config/ext.properties";
    String remoteFilePath = "file://" + remote;
    URL url = new URL(remoteFilePath);
    System.out.println("Begin to open " + LocalDateTime.now());
    URLConnection con  = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    //do somework with InputStream
    System.out.println("Finish open " + LocalDateTime.now());
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error occur " + LocalDateTime.now());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, for some reason SERVER_A cannot be accessed, the code above will run into Exception block after like 5-40 seconds. I want the code to handle like this if it cannot get the connection in 2 seconds, throw the exception.

I also try to add `con.setConnectionTimeout(2000)` after `URLConnection con  = url.openConnection();` But it doesn't work... How can I resolve this?

Comment: The `file:` scheme is for a local file system. Is that a mounted network drive?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Yes, it is network drive.

Comment: Have you also tried to set a read timeout (`con.setReadTimeout(1000)`)?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele after ```con.setConnectionTimeout(2000)```? Tried, still not working..and exception line is throw on ```InputStream is = con.getInputStream();```

Answer (score 0):

Access to UNC-paths are passed to the operating system, so setting timeouts in the `URLConnection` won't work (and the whole thing wouldn't work on an e.g. Linux system). There are libraries like jcifs that allow you to access UNC-paths without going via the operating system (limited to SMBv1 though) where you can set timeouts and other things.